# Install third party libs to be available from within and without the Google App Engine dev server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The official documentation for Google App Engine with python recommends using a virtualenv and installing third party libs into a subdirectory of the project root:

```
$ source /path/to/my/virtualenv/bin/activate
$ cd my/project/root
$ mkdir lib
$ pip install -t lib sqlalchemy
```

The docs then say to make an `appengine_config.py` file in the project root with the following content:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

This all works in the sense that the dev server can find sqlalchemy at run time. However, my virtualenv itself cannot. If I do this

```
$ python
>>> import sqlalchemy
```

I get an import error.
This makes testing things apart from the dev server awkward/impossible.
Is there some pip trick or something similar I can use to make the libs available both from within and without the dev server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow a variation of the same steps but with

```
$ ln -s {virtualenv}/lib/python2.7/site-packages lib
```

This way a pip install in the virtualenv automatically goes to the lib directory as well.

Every pip install would then be available to the virtualenv's  python and to the dev_appserver without supplying the target folder to make testing things bearable. Eg.:

```
$ pip install sqlalchemy
```

Comment: Good, simple solution.