# With Google's Flask skeleton for Python App Engine, how can install additional libraries with Pip?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, pip

To install dependences, the [appengine-python-flask-skeleton docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-flask-skeleton) advise running this command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib
```

That works simply enough.

Now say I want to add the [Requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Ideally I just add it to the `requirements.txt` file:

```
# This requirements file lists all third-party dependencies for this project.
#
# Run 'pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib/' to install these dependencies
# in `lib/` subdirectory.
#
# Note: The `lib` directory is added to `sys.path` by `appengine_config.py`.
Flask==0.10
requests
```

And then re-run the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib
```

However, as [this Github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1489) for pip notes, pip is not idempotent with the `-T` option recommended by Google here. The existing flask packages will be re-added and this will lead to the following error when running the devapp

```
ImportError: cannot import name exceptions
```

How can I best work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said, updating pip solves the issue for many, but for what it's worth I think you can get around all of this if the use of [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) is an option. Symlink `/path/to/virtualenv's/sitepackages/` to `lib/` and just always keep an up to date `requirements.txt` file. There are no duplication of packages this way and one won't have to manually install dependencies. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30447848/2295256

Comment: This is a nice alternative. Are there any complications? I don't imagine it's too hard to piece together from the links you've provided, but can you link to a site that provides a step-by-step guide for setting this up?

Comment: @klenwell Haven't had complications yet. This is sitting somewhere in my drafts. I'll clean it up and post a link here :)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest version of pip solved my problem (that issue had been closed):

```
pip install -U pip
```

Otherwise, as noted in that thread, you can always just wipe out your `lib` directory and reinstall from scratch. One note of warning: if you manually added additional packages to the `lib` directory not tracked in `requirements.txt`, they would be lost and have to be re-installed manually.